# Entering Canada from the US by bus

Tags: canada, borders, eta, maltese-citizens, customs-and-immigration

I shall be visiting Canada during the summer, however, I will be entering the country by bus from New York. Would I still need an eTA to cross the border?

I will be coming from Malta (Europe+EU member) with a Maltese passport. Will the passport alone suffice for land travel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you do not need an eTA but you must still bring your passport. You can easily check this using the [Canadian Government site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp). Here is what it says for citizens of Malta:

[image]